# Firebase + Workspace Add-on: Service account expires constantly. Unable to determine why

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I currently have a Google Workspace Add-on deployed in the marketplace.  It is using the [Firebase App Script Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) to connect the Firebase Real Time Database to the App Script project.    The service account that facilitates this connection has recently expired and when re-established with a new Private Key, it’ll work for a short period then stop again (30-45 minutes).

To my knowledge, I appear to be using the Service Account as outlined in the reference provided with the [Library correctly for Add-ons](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-with-a-service-account).

This Service account worked for over a year and just started a couple days ago out of the blue.

Once I issue a new private key for the service account I can test the service and it won’t work right away, I have to remove the URLwhitelist from the Manifest to be able to have the service test successfully.  I can then add the whitelist back to the add-ons Manifest however it can’t be published this way.   I’m not sure that's directly related but seems to point toward the Manifest of the Workspace Add-ons.

Are there logs or information on what would cause the private key to expire?